# How ASP.NET CORE uses RPC to call other API interfaces

Tags: asp.net-core, rpc

I now have a new project of asp.net core web api, I use it as the main language, but some interfaces are completed with java, and now the company has changed to asp.net core as the main language. I can use asp.net core to complete these interfaces again, but it doesn't make sense. So I checked the information online and suggested that I use rpc to call the previous interface. How can I do it?

Take one of the java interfaces as an example

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Send email registration verification code")
    @GetMapping("send_code")
    public JsonData sendRegisterCode(@ApiParam("Recipient") @RequestParam(value = "to", required = true) String to,
                                     @ApiParam("Verification code") @RequestParam(value = "captcha", required = true) String captcha,
                                     HttpServletRequest request
    ) {

        String key = getCaptchaKey(request);
        String cacheCaptcha = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
        //Matching graphic verification code

        if (captcha != null && cacheCaptcha != null && captcha.equalsIgnoreCase(cacheCaptcha)) {
            //success
            redisTemplate.delete(key);
            JsonData jsonData = notifyService.sendCode(SendCodeEnum.USER_REGISTER, to);
            return jsonData;

        } else {
            return JsonData.buildResult(BizCodeEnum.CODE_CAPTCHA_ERROR);
        }

    }

    private String getCaptchaKey(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String ip = CommonUtil.getIpAddr(request);
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
        String key = "user-service:captcha:" + CommonUtil.MD5(ip + userAgent);
        return key;
    }
```

How can I call the modified api? Any suggestions on the documentation and code are very much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can use grpc template to create project：

[image]

Reference documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

If you want to use on an existing project, you can do this：

1.**Add required NuGet packages**:

```
Install-Package Grpc.Net.Client
Install-Package Google.Protobuf
Install-Package Grpc.Tools
```

2.**Add greet.proto**

> Create a Protos folder in the gRPC client project.
>
> Copy the Protos\greet.proto file from the gRPC Greeter service to the
> Protos folder in the gRPC client project.
>
> Update the namespace inside the greet.proto file to the project's
> namespace:
> option csharp_namespace = "GrpcGreeterClient";

Add an item group with a  element that refers to the greet.proto file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Client" />
</ItemGroup>
```

3.For the specific steps of Create the Greeter client and Test the gRPC client with the gRPC Greeter service, refer to the official documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The question doesn't mention gRPC and the annotations and the JSON formatting in the code imply that it is a web API, but the question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: I‘m considering using grpc protocol to complete, I will go to research, thank you.